# How do I force list or scalar context in Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm a little confused about some of the details of list and scalar contexts in Perl and I'm hoping someone can help me out a bit. My ultimate goal is to compare the number of elements in two arrays, except that one of the arrays is an anonymous array and I can't figure out to get Perl to tell me how many elements it has. This is what I typed into the debugger:`

```
DB<10> @a = ([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[10,11])

DB<11> @b = $a[1]

DB<12> $c = @b

DB<13> p $c
1             # Why didn't this print out 5?

DB<14> $d = $a[1]

DB<15> p @$d
56789

DB<16> p $$d
Not a SCALAR reference at (eval 17)[/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9/perl5db.pl:638] line 2.

DB<17> @e = @a[1]

DB<18> p @e
ARRAY(0x87c358)

DB<19> p ${@e}
```

I'm out of combinations of funny characters to try, can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: See http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`[]` will create an array reference (which is a scalar).

`$a[1]` points to `[5,6,7,8,9]` (the array reference)

`@b = $a[1]` will create a new array with one item in it (the array reference).

You need to dereference the arrayref.

`@b = @{$a[1]}`

At which point you can get the number of items in it:

`print scalar @b`

Comment: or just `print scalar @{$a[1]}`

Comment: read `perldoc perlreftut` (perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) or the data structures cookbook `perldoc perldsc` (perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)